# How to set a serverless cron job to run after 10 days from first deploy and than to run every day

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cron, boto3, serverless-framework

I need some help setting up the schedule for a lambda function that I deploy with serverless framework.
It should start running daily, but only 10 days after it has been deployed.

Is this possible?

```
functions:
  prerequisites:
    handler: prerequisites.prerequisites
  keyRotation:
    handler: iamKeyRotation.main
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 6 * * ? *)
```

I just set the function to run every day.

Comment: There's no way to implement that with a single lambda and a single cron. Why would you deploy the function 10 days in advance of when it's needed? You could deploy and then throttle it with 0 concurrency until day 10, but, it wouldn't be automated unless you created another lambda to change the concurrency on day 10.

Comment: Because I will be implementing this on multiple accounts and I wouldn't want to change the function a second time for each account.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way in cron to define a pattern that is daily but has a 10 day wait built in.  From your comments it seems like you're deploying to multiple accounts and don't want to touch it twice.

My recommendation would be to write a "deployer" lambda that takes in some configuration like account number, date, etc., and deploys the lambda when needed on the day it's needed with a daily cron.  Then you just update the configuration to reference when a specific account needs the lambda to be deployed.